# How to turn off beep codes on a Supermicro X9DR3-F motherboard?

Tags: supermicro

The system is a Supermicro X9DR3-F.

One of the hard drives has failed and my RAID array is rebuilding. This takes a long time, and the system beeps every 2 seconds (for about 1 second) to let me know a drive has failed.

This is driving me to insanity since I need to work in the server room the whole day.

Does someone know how to turn it off? I couldn't find any option for that in the BIOS and I no longer have the manual.

Comment: You need to remove the failed hard drive, put in a good one and then the RAID array will (should) rebuild silently. That works for us. I would not wait long at all before replacing the drive.

Comment: I've already done that but it keeps beeping. The server only stores some vms which get backed up every night so I'm not too worried... It's up and running so work can get done today but I just want some silence for now :) I was planning an upgrade to solid state anyway

Comment: Thanks. We have had drives fail at clients (so they beep annoyingly), then that stops on replacement. I recall one place where there was an option in the RAID app (not the Server app) to silence the alarm. You might look there.

Comment: I think I just have a bad spare... it is the only one left... I haven't yet looked into the raid config thanks for the tip!

Comment: I am pretty sure you are correct. A good drive should not be setting off an alarm (experience with a number of servers)

Comment: I can silence the alarm in the RAID bios, but when you exit you need to CRTL-ALT-DEL which resets the alarm...

Answer (score 2):

I've found the solution. In the RAID controller, go to properties and keep click next until you see "alarm control". Set to silence or disabled and click submit.

Full info comes from [the official Lenovo site](https://support.lenovo.com/be/en/solutions/ht078386):

> To disable or silence alarm:
>
> - If the alarm is disabled, it will never turn on again (i.e.: due to a different issue).
> - If the alarm is silenced, it will turn back on when there is another issue.  In this case, it will also turn back on after a reboot.
>
> To disable/silence alarm from the Web BIOS Configuration Utility (CU):
>
> - Enter the Web BIOS CU by clicking <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> at boot.
> - Select the controller affected by the issue.
> - Select “Controller Properties”.
> - Click “Next” until locating the “Alarm Control” entry.
> - Select “Disable”, “Enable”, or “Silence” from the drop-down menu and click “Submit”.
>
> To disable/silence alarm from MegaRAID Storage Management:
>
> - Select the controller affected by the issue.
> - Select the “Physical” tab.
> - Right click the controller entry on the left pane of the screen.
> - Select “Disable Alarm” or “Silence Alarm”.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to managing via the RAID controller interface, you can use either MegaCLI or StorCli commands.

Disabling the alarm is perhaps not advised as you will not get any alarms until it is re-enabled.

Silencing the alarm will do so until the next reboot or the next event that would trigger the alarm.

```
MegaCli64 -AdpSetProp <AlarmEnbl | AlarmDsbl | AlarmSilence> -aN
```

The N is the adapter number. For example, this silences the alarm on adapter 0.

```
Megaraid CLI> MegaCli -AdpSetProp AlarmSilence -a0

Adapter 0: Set alarm to Silenced success.

Exit Code: 0x00
```

In StorCli, the equivalent is:

```
storcli /cx set alarm=<on | off | silence>
```